# Is there desktop motherboard that supports notebook hardware?

Tags: motherboard

Is there desktop motherboard that supports notebook hardware?

I have notebook HP Pavilion dv7-1160er without accumulator, that can not hardly use graphic card because it too hot and system can go to blue screen at this time. That's why I want to "convert" it to Desktop computer.

I know that there is specific socket for CPU, RAM and Graphic card. So is there any desktop motherboard that can support my notebook's CPU, RAM and Graphic Card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [HP's specifications](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=125&prodSeriesId=3756677&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=3756677&objectID=c01601474), your laptop has the Intel Core 2 Duo P7350 CPU and nVidia GeForce 9600M GT GPU.

There are some desktop motherboards that support mobile CPUs and SO-DIMMs (such as the [Jetway NF93R-LF](http://www.jetway.com.tw/jw/ipcboard_view.asp?productid=652&proname=NF93R-LF) or the [IBASE MI945P](http://www.ibase-usa.com/MI945P.html)), but they're all in the mini-ITX form factor meant for small home servers, HTPCs and other such applications. Considering that the P7350 CPU is several generations old now, it might be more economical to get a modern motherboard with a 2nd or 3rd generation Core i3 and DDR3 RAM, which will likely have similar power consumption but far superior performance.

But if you're on a budget or don't have very high requirements, then both of the boards linked above seem to be good choices for re-using your CPU and RAM.

The GPU is where it gets really tricky. The vast majority of laptops have the graphics card soldered on the motherboard (even if it's a discrete part with its own video RAM). In the rare cases that the graphics card is removable, it uses the proprietary [MXM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_PCI_Express_Module) standard (of which there are several revisions, to complicate matters further), and you'd need an MXM-to-PCIe adapter, which don't seem to exist.

Other components you might be able to use from your laptop include the hard drive (using a [2.5-to-3.5" mounting adapter](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=2.5%20to%203.5%20hdd%20mounting)), the WLAN card (using a [mini-PCIe-to-PCIe adapter card](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=mini%20pcie%20to%20pcie%20wireless%20adapter)) and the display panel (using an [LVDS controller board](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=laptop%20lvds%20controller) + power supply).

Comment: So graphic card is useless? Mini-ITX motherboard is normal. About buying new CPU - not meaningful.

Comment: I can't seem to find any information about whether or not your laptop has an MXM GPU. But yes, I'd say forget reusing the graphics card. Also see my answer, I updated it with some more information. Also, if a mini-ITX system with an old C2D is fine, then check out that Jetway motherboard I linked to.

Comment: I find that this graphic card uses MXM II

Comment: That you will say about this http://www.liantec.com/product/tbm/TBM-1620.htm ? This will support MXM-II graphic card?

Comment: Nice find! That does indeed seem to support MXM graphics cards. However, from what I can see, it doesn't convert to standard PCI Express, but rather uses some kind of proprietary "Tiny-Bus" connector that combines PCI Express, PCI and AGP (see [here](http://www.liantec.com/product/tbm/TBM_brief.htm)), which means you'll probably have to go for one of their own motherboards as well (not necessarily a bad thing, just means your choices are restricted a bit).